# send an image from an Activity to another Activity

Tags: android

I have two activities in android studio. In Activity1 I have a button or image view and I want to when I clicked on it, send an image to Activity2 and when I get to Activity2, the image will be there. And when in Activity1 I clicked the button for second time, the Image in Activity2 will be gone.
 but I dont want click on image view and go to second activity. I want to click on it in first activity and just send the image to sec activity without  go to sec activity automatically. and when I went to sec activity manually, the image will be there. And when I return to first activity and click the image view again, the image in sec activity will be disappear . how can I do that?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    byte[] bytesImage;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    //use shared preferences to save button click count
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    String hide_image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        final ImageView imageview=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (sharedPreferences.getString("activity1", "").equals("1")) {
                    //image is already clicked once
                    hide_image="1";
                }
                else{
                    hide_image="0";
                    imageview.buildDrawingCache(); //your imageview
                    Bitmap bitmap = imageview.getDrawingCache();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, ba);
                    //save the image byte array
                    bytesImage=ba.toByteArray();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    //set 1 as button is clicked
                    editor.putString("activity1", "1");
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });


        Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("byteArray", bytesImage);
                i.putExtra("hideImage", hide_image);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: hi, my question is different . please read it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first activity: use

```
 byte[] bytesImage;
 public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
 //use shared preferences to save button click count
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
 String hide_image;
```

in onCreate()

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Then set imageview click listener

```
imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                if (sharedPreferences.getString("activity1", "").equals("1")) {
                    //image is already clicked once
                    hide_image="1";
                }
           else{
               hide_image="0";
               Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
               ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
               bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, ba);
               //save the image byte array
               bytesImage=ba.toByteArray()
               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    //set 1 as button is clicked
                    editor.putString("activity1", "1");
                    editor.commit();
            }
        }
    });


manualButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("byteArray", bytesImage);
                i.putExtra("hideImage", hide_image);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

In your second activity

```
String hide=getIntent().getStringExtra("hideImage");
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
if (hide.equals("0") {
    //show image only in first click
    ImageView previewThumbnail = new ImageView(this);   
    previewThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmp);//set bitmap to imageview
}
```

Comment: Its not a good idea to send whole image via intent.Just pass its path

Comment: @Androidjack sure it makes sense...

Comment: in second activity, how can i set bitmap to imageview

Comment: just reference your imageView like imageview im= findViewById(R.id.imageview_name); then im.setImageBitmap(b);

Comment: Tnx. Please read the main question again. I dont want click on image view and go to second activity. I want to click on it in first activity and just send the image to sec activity without  go to sec activity automatically. and when I went to sec activity manually, the image will be there. And when I return to first activity and click the image view again, the image in sec activity will be disappear . how can I do that?

Comment: what do u mean go to sec activity manually??

Comment: I mean go to sec acticity by another button not the imageView that contains the photo. And the main problem is that when i selected the imageview and sent the image to sec activity, i want to select the image for second time and the image in act2 will be disappear.tnx

Comment: @NeamatTabani see the edited answer...don;t forget to accept it..

Comment: tnx for your answer. it seems what i want. i used your codes and changed it but it dosent work. please look at my codes that added to question and tell what should i do and where i have to change or added more codes?

Comment: what portion did not work?

Comment: when i click on imageView and THEN go to second activity, there is no image in sec activity

Comment: what have to do in     //use shared preferences to save button click count
    portion?

Comment: yes...it used for count the click...see the edited second activity and image click listener ---also debug your code ...which value is passing...it should work

Comment: it dosent work :(  . may i send you the project and take a look plz?

Comment: i cant mark it yet because this error : Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: how can i send you the project?

Comment: can you write your Email plz?

Comment: i accepted it. and im sending you codes...

Comment: i sent you the mail. did you get it?

Comment: hi again. the codes you sent me dosent work well. i think you did not understand my question truly :(